# cascades of templates does not work

Tags: c++, templates

I am a beginner of c++ meta programming.
Now I test a code which is on a text book.
The following code is a copy of the code but it give me an error message
at line(1). At line(1), it seems the code tries to call Layer2::function with template keyword because it is following another template. Unfortunately, my compiler give me an error message, "error: expected ‘;’ before ‘::’ token.". Can anyone find a problem of the code?
Thank you very much.

```
template<typename T>
class Layer0 {
public:
    template<int L1>
    class Layer1 {
    public:
        template<int L2>
        class Layer2 {
        public:
            virtual void function(void);
        };
    };
};

template<typename T, int L1>
class LayerTest {
public:
    void pointer (typename Layer0<T>::template Layer1<L1>::template Layer2<L1>* ptr) {
        // At the following line(1), I got an error message, error: expected ‘;’ before ‘::’ token.
        ptr->template Layer2<L1>::function();  // (1) inhibit call of virtual function
    }
};
```

Comment: Builds here without an instantiation. Where is your [testcase](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The template Layer2 is not in scope at the point where you used it, that you are calling "line(1)".  I suggest several typedef or using lines to make the type incantations easier.  Alternately, you could use decltype.  I think that would be `ptr->decltype(*ptr)::function();`

Comment: Well it fails on [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5c7e490614d29bd9) it works on [CLANG](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fc99e16d368daae). I guess it boils down to which compiler is right...

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Notice the comment saying the intent is to make a non virtual call to a virtual function (call based on the compile time type, rather than the run time type).

Comment: Thank you very much everyone. Honestly said, I could not follow some points above. But I believe the second comment of JSF is right. And I will try it with CLANG according to the comment by 101010. Thank you very much.

Comment: And I used gcc version 4.8.4.